# Changing maptlotlib's default style breaks legend markers

Tags: python, matplotlib, seaborn

Changing maptlotlib's default style to seaborn causes *some* legend markers not to display properly.

Consider the following MWE in which all the legend markers from the [official documentation](https://matplotlib.org/api/markers_api.html) are plotted. First the plots are made with the default style, and then with Seaborn's style.

```py
from matplotlib.lines import Line2D
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

# https://matplotlib.org/api/markers_api.html
keys = ["point", "pixel", "circle", r"triangle_down", r"triangle_up",
        r"triangle_left", r"triangle_right", r"tri_down", r"tri_up", 
        r"tri_left", r"tri_right", "octagon", "square", "pentagon",
        "plus (filled)", "star", "hexagon1", "hexagon2", "plus", "x",
        "x (filled)", "diamond", r"thin_diamond", "vline", "hline"]

values = [".", ",", "o", "v", "^", "<", ">", "1", "2", "3", "4", "8", "s", "p",
          "P", "*", "h", "H", "+", "x", "X", "D", "d", "|", "_"]

# Make dictionary of markers and their description
markers = dict(zip(keys, values))

# Plot all markers with default style and seaborn style
for style in 'default', 'seaborn':
    plt.style.use(style)

    # Create handles for legend call
    legend_elements = []
    for key, value in markers.items():
        legend_elements.append(Line2D([0], [0], markersize=10, marker=value,
                                      label=key))
    # Create the figure
    fig, ax = plt.subplots(figsize=[6, 4])
    ax.legend(handles=legend_elements, loc='center', ncol=3)
    plt.show()
```

The above gave me the following two graphs:

[image: default style legends]
[image: seaborn style legends]

Notice that with the default style all the markers display as expected. However, with seaborn some markers do not (tri_down, tri_up, tri_left, tri_right, plus, x, vline). It looks like the filled markers work, but the others do not. Could this be something to do with fill colour vs edge colour?

Could somebody please explain why the seaborn markers don't display as I expect or what I'm doing wrong? Thanks.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You are correct. For some reason, seaborn's style sheet has a line width of zero for the markers, which makes the unfilled markers disappear

```
print("Value of 'lines.markeredgewidth' in rcParams")
for style in 'default', 'seaborn':
    plt.style.use(style)
    print(style, ': ', matplotlib.rcParams['lines.markeredgewidth'])

>>

Value of 'lines.markeredgewidth' in rcParams
default :  1.0
seaborn :  0.0
```

Changing this parameter in rcParams prevents this from happening:

```
from matplotlib.lines import Line2D
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

# https://matplotlib.org/api/markers_api.html
keys = ["point", "pixel", "circle", r"triangle_down", r"triangle_up",
        r"triangle_left", r"triangle_right", r"tri_down", r"tri_up", 
        r"tri_left", r"tri_right", "octagon", "square", "pentagon",
        "plus (filled)", "star", "hexagon1", "hexagon2", "plus", "x",
        "x (filled)", "diamond", r"thin_diamond", "vline", "hline"]

values = [".", ",", "o", "v", "^", "<", ">", "1", "2", "3", "4", "8", "s", "p",
          "P", "*", "h", "H", "+", "x", "X", "D", "d", "|", "_"]

# Make dictionary of markers and their description
markers = dict(zip(keys, values))

# Plot all markers with default style and seaborn style
for style in 'default', 'seaborn':
    plt.style.use(style)
    matplotlib.rcParams['lines.markeredgewidth'] = 1.
    # Create handles for legend call
    legend_elements = []
    for key, value in markers.items():
        legend_elements.append(Line2D([0], [0], markersize=10, marker=value,
                                      label=key))
    # Create the figure
    fig, ax = plt.subplots(figsize=[6, 4])
    ax.legend(handles=legend_elements, loc='center', ncol=3)
    plt.show()
```

Comment: Excellent, thanks for this explanation and solution! It is peculiar that seaborn's style should set the marker edge width to 0. I can't think of any advantages of this choice.